# Factoring Linq Where clause for different EF objets

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm trying to factorize the `Where` clause in following code:

```cs
public async Task ExecuteAsync(BatchProcessingModel bpm)
{
    using (_dbFoo = new FooEntities(_fooConnexionString))
    {
        var bprInBdd = await _dbFoo.BatchProcessing
            .Where(x => x.FooAttr1 == bpm.FooAttr1 && x.FooAttr2 == bpm.FooAttr2 && ...)
            .ToListAsync();
        var bprLocal = _dbFoo.BatchProcessing.Local
            .Where(x => x.FooAttr1 == bpm.FooAttr1 && x.FooAttr2 == bpm.FooAttr2 && ...)
            .ToList();

        if (bprLocal.Count == 0 && bprInBdd.Count == 0)
        {
            // add new BatchProcessing in BDD
        }
    }
}
```

So far, I have tried to add a pseudo equal method to `BatchProcessingModel` like so:

```cs
public bool EqualProcess(BatchProcessing bpr)
{
    return this.FooAttr1 == bpr.FooAttr1 && this.FooAttr2 == bpr.FooAttr2 && ...;
}
```

```cs
var bprInBdd = await _dbFoo.BatchProcessing
    .Where(x => bpm.EqualProcess(x))
    .ToListAsync();
var bprLocal = _dbFoo.BatchProcessing.Local
    .Where(x => bpm.EqualProcess(x))
    .ToList();
```

But I get an error that says `Linq to Entities does not recognize the method`. It seems Linq is trying to transform `bpm.EqualProcess(x)` into a SQL statement but can't do so. Maybe because it doesn't try to read past `EqualProcess`.

Is there any way I can do a cleaner code? Or should I just stick to the duplication of where clauses?

Comment: So I already found the duplicated thread but didn't understand the answer at the time.
I managed to solve my problem with
`Expression<Func<BatchProcessing, bool> equalProcess = x => x.FooAttr1 == ...;`
and
`var bprInBdd = await _dbFoo.BatchProcessing.Where(equalProcess).ToListAsync();`
`var bprLocal = _dbFoo.BatchProcessing.AsQueryable().Where(equalProcess).ToList();`

Comment: If you wanna stick to linq to entities you should pass an Expression<Func<T,TV>> instead of a Func<T, TV> you are passing in now

Comment: wow that's lame i forgot pressing add comment but apparently you already know now :D